# Ruby class << self

Tags: ruby, class, self

I know what

```
class << self
```

does. But what is the underlying mechanism of this trick?

`<<` in Ruby is Binary Left Shift Operator

So we are doing binary left shift on `class` variable ?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not just binary left shift - `<<` in Ruby is also the [singleton class definition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Singleton+Classes) syntax. This syntax is used because all objects representing classes in Ruby are singleton classes.

Comment: as well as an alternative syntax to Array#push(), e.g. arr << element.

Comment: @Jakobinsky: that's just plain operator overloading

Comment: It's not a method, it's syntax.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not so much "operator overloading" as simple "method definition". the `<<` method *does* perform bitwise shifts on `Fixnum` objects but is totally undefined for generic objects. You can't overload something if it's not there to overload!

Comment: @Gareth: hm, yes and do. it's more than a method, it's an operator (eg: there are precedence rules), right?